# Can't login into phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been battling with this since 9AM and it is past 7:30 PM. My application was not able to communicate with mySQL. So I wanted to make sure I could get into it through phpMyAdmin. I can bring up the login screen(via localhost/phpmyadmin) in my browser, but It won't take my user and password. I've tried stopping it, running `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`, and then starting it. No dice. when I type `mysql` at the CLI I get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

This makes sense since I don't have a */var/run/* directory. 
I tried `mysql -u richb201 -p`  but I get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Is there anyway for me to remove *mysql* and just reinstall it?

Here is my current *mysqld.conf* which is NOT in the */run/* directory

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway for me to remove mysql and just reinstall it?

Yes there is:

```
sudo apt remove mysql-server
```

or

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server
```

The latter will ensure that all packages related to the installation are removed including configuration files.

Then to reinstall:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

To set mysql root password run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command.

Comment: Thanks. when I run either remove or purge or install I get: Unable to locate package mysql. What to do?

Comment: Are you sure mysql is installed? What is the output of `systemctl status mysql`? also  try `sudo apt purge mysql-server`. Also the firewall could be the issue. `sudo ufw allow mysql` would resolve it.

Comment: What is the output of systemctl status mysql? Unit mysql.service could not be found.  I ran all of your suggestions. when I type $ mysql I get: mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Run `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: Ran it. Now when I type mysql I get : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'richb201'@'localhost' (using password: NO). Does that mean it is still there?

Comment: What do you get when you run `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90151/discussion-between-denmu-and-richard-bernstein).